# How to prevent key binding execution repetition on Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, rcp, key-bindings

I need to prevent my application to perform the same action over and over again when that action is associated with a key biding, while the user is holding the trigger sequence.

I need to emulate the same behavior that can be achieved implementing a KeyListener#keyReleased, and perform the associated action only when the user releases the sequence.

There's anyway to do that?

Comment: After a lot of search, I can't find any satisfactory solution. So, I just removed the key bindings from plugin.xml and implemented all of them on KeyDown event from Display class, like this:

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter( SWT.KeyUp, new MyListener() );

Comment: I too am looking for some way to have my key bindings recognize specific events such as keyPressed and keyReleased.  I appreciate the fact that you came back to your question and left comments about what you found out about the lack of availability of this functionality.